# Update or fix payments API gateaway

Tags: authorize.net

Right now have old legacy site around 10-20 years. Gateway API provided by Authorize.net. As I see it's perl scripts with requests to payments APIs looking like that

```
$trans{'x_version'}='3.1';
    $trans{'x_login'}='';
    $trans{'x_tran_key'}="";
    $trans{'x_delim_data'}='TRUE';
    $trans{'x_delim_char'}='|';
    if($test_mode>0) { $trans{'x_test_request'}='TRUE'; }
    ....

    $trans{'id'}=$row[0];
    $trans{'created'}=$row[1];
    $trans{'status'}=$row[2];

    # Customer Data
    $trans{'x_cust_id'}=$row[13];
    $trans{'x_customer_ip'}=$row[14];

    $trans{'x_email'}=$row[15]; # - to check AVS;
    if(length($trans{'x_email'})) {
        $trans{'x_email'} =~ s/@/&#64/g; # encode email by authorize.net spec requirement
        $trans{'x_email_customer'}='TRUE';
    } else {
        $trans{'x_email_customer'}='FALSE';
    }

    $trans{'x_first_name'}=$row[18];
    $trans{'x_last_name'}=$row[19];
    $trans{'x_company'}=$row[20];

    $trans{'x_address'}=$row[21]; # - to check AVS;
    $trans{'x_city'}=$row[22]; # - to check AVS;
    $trans{'x_state'}=$row[23]; # - to check AVS;
    $trans{'x_zip'}=$row[24]; # - to check AVS;
    $trans{'x_country'}='USA';
    $trans{'x_phone'}=$row[25]; # - to check AVS;

    #$trans{'x_fp_sequence'}=1;
    #$trans{'x_fp_timestamp'}=time();

    $trans{'x_ship_to_first_name'}=$trans{'x_first_name'};
    $trans{'x_ship_to_last_name'}=$trans{'x_last_name'};
    $trans{'x_ship_to_company'}=$trans{'x_company'};
    $trans{'x_ship_to_address'}=$trans{'x_address'};
    $trans{'x_ship_to_city'}=$trans{'x_city'};
    $trans{'x_ship_to_state'}=$trans{'x_state'};
    $trans{'x_ship_to_zip'}=$trans{'x_zip'};
    $trans{'x_ship_to_country'}=$trans{'x_country'};

    # Invoice Information

    $trans{'x_invoice_num'}=$row[16];
    $trans{'x_description'}=$row[17];

    # Transaction Data

    $trans{'x_amount'}=$row[4];
    $trans{'x_currency_code'}='USD';
    $trans{'x_method'}=$row[5];
    $trans{'x_type'}=$row[3];
    and etc.
    with request to 
    $req = POST( "https://secure2.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll", [ %trans ] );
```

It's AIM Name Value Pair method and that not working more after 7.04.2020 and return status 3 credit card required error. As i understand last change in code of server was more then half year ago. 
So i'm not sure what more good does in that situation.
Be happy to any help or advice.

Comment: Have you attempted *any* debugging?

Comment: Yeap i try debugging and it was my big fall i must try repeate the logick of the script in my enviroment in first moment when i see that error but i not do that. When i write script for testing i try save them and see what disk is full and transaction not process correct because they can't do correct row about transaction in Database. I am still surprised how the rest of the logic did not fall and continued to work.